# Transition from MFC to QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Currently all our GUI components are written in MFC. Our build environment is:

> **VC 6**
>
> **Windows XP**

I have no idea whether:

1) We can replace all MFC components with Qt, without changing build environment ?

2) Qt will work with VC6 as any other library?

You answers will help me in getting started, In the mean time I have installed Qt 4 and am trying to build some samples.

Comment: an alternative - considering your old compiler - would be to upgrade first to vs2008/mfc - if portability is not an issue.

Comment: I strongly support Anders Karlsson's advice.  VC++ 6 is old and idiosyncratic.  You will find that less and less third-party software will work on it.  VC++ 2008 is almost completely standard-conforming, so it will age far better.

Comment: thx Anders , David..I consider your suggestions..I will propose same to team :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. If we can replace all MFC components with QT, without changing build environment ?

Yes, you even get a MFC/Qt migration framework cf [qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Windows/qtwinmigrate/](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Windows/qtwinmigrate/)

> 2. Will Qt work with VC6 as any other library ?

VC6 is more than 10 years old!

Qt supports VC6 until version 4.5
The next release (4.6) will drop VC6 support cf [qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6-snapshot/qt4-6-intro.html#performance-optimizations](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6-snapshot/qt4-6-intro.html#performance-optimizations)

Comment: Oops for the VC6 support by Qt, I've confused with win9x support.
It's unclear which version of Qt still support VC6. I guess the latest one is Qt-4.4 cf http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/supported-platforms.html
Qt 4.5 specifically flagged VC6 as unsupported: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/supported-platforms.html

Comment: The links here seem broken, and most google searches lead to an old archived version of the framework. https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-solutions/qt-solutions.git/ is the most up-to-date version that I've found.

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn’t use VC6 with Qt 4.5. ([see doc](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/supported-platforms.html))

Apart from that: If your project compiles with Qt, you can easily* switch to Qt components. Qt uses its own componentens anyway, so there’s no other dependencies involved.

However, to set up the Qt environment, you might need to do a few changes to your build system, unless you’re not working with `QObject`s. (Think of the moc pre-processor.)

*: easily in the sense of being able to start using Qt components. The amount of work needed to actually migrate MFC components to those of Qt is something I don’t know anything about.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing MFC to QT requires a big work to do. First of all you should think whether you need that. Second, Qt could be integrated with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I learned something very useful when trying to port one client's MFC application to Qt.

I do a *lot* of refactoring.  That doesn't scare me at all.  However, I am usually *incrementally* changing things.  That makes a huge difference.

I started porting the MFC application to Qt just after the LGPL version of Qt was released, but **before the LGPL release of 'qtwinmigrate'**  (get it at ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/solutions/lgpl/).  At the time, I thought Qt was going to hold on to the MFC migration stuff as an incentive for the commercial license.

I had to convert a good number of files before ever being able to compile the project.  Once the very basics were up and running, I slowly re-added dialogs until the functionality matched the original version.  This was *much harder* than being able to keep your existing MFC app running as is and slowly replacing dialogs.

So, the point is...  **USE QTWINMIGRATE!**

Oh yeah...  and don't use VC6.  Upgrade to something more recent.